# How do I form a great relationship with my advisor?

Tags: advisor, group-dynamics, research-group

I'm currently doing research work at a university for two years before I begin my doctoral studies. I just arrived here around 3 months ago. From what I've gathered, my advisor is genuinely a very kind person who makes the research group a great place to work, and I think that I'd really like to stay where I'm currently working at for my doctoral studies.

I just wanted to ask; how do I form a great, organic relationship with my advisor (ideally I want to get to the point with them where we interact on a friendly, casual level) and impress them to the point that they'd want to take me on as their student full-time? How do I eventually bring it up to my advisor that I'd like to stay working for them/at this institution after my two years here? Ideally, I'd like actionable things that I can do!

For context, I'm doing research in theoretical physics.

Comment: Be mindful of the possibility that your adviser may not be interested in interacting with you "on a friendly, casual level".

Comment: I edited the question a bit - normally the rule is to only ask one question at a time, otherwise the question might get closed for being to broad.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. After 3 months, you should already "interact on a friendly, casual level". If that isn't the case, the advisor might prefer a more formal environment and you can't really change that. Have you had frequent interactions witrh your advisor?

Comment: @DanRomik. Maybe I wasn't clear here. I'm already at that "friendly, casual" level. Maybe I'm referring to an even more casual level.

Comment: @Roland Yes! Per my above reply, I've been at that "friendly, casual" level in my opinion. Maybe I don't have a proper gauge of how other students interact with their advisors.